# Trouble aligning 2 child divs inside a parent div using float:left and float:right

Tags: css, html

I know the answer is simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
<div id="header">
<div id="30">
    <img src="../images/logo.png" width="97" height="97" />
</div>
<div id="company">
    <img src="../images/company.png" width="370" height="97" />
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>

#header {
width:960px;
background-color:#e9e9e9;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding-bottom:15px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#30 {
float:left;
}
#company {
float:right;
}
```

I couldn't figure out how to post the code from jsfiddle. The result is the "30" div aligned to the left side of the parent and the "company" div aligned to the right, but it's dropped down a line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first problem is that `#30` isn't a valid ID — CSS doesn't like it when the first character is a number. Try `#thirty`.

Here's a JSBin showing it working, albeit with JSBin logos.
http://jsbin.com/IJaseKa/1

Comment: Ha. This fixed my problem. I never knew that divs had to start with a letter. THANKS!!

Comment: Actually, #30 is a perfectly valid ID. In HTML5. It's just that CSS has issues with it. See http://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/

Comment: @knouroozi you may want to update your answer just a smidge. Variable names can start with other characters as well ("_30", "$30", even "π30"), not just letters.

Comment: Thanks Justin and j08691, just did.

Answer (score 3):

CSS has trouble with IDs beginning with a number. Use something with letters instead.

Here is the working code

http://jsfiddle.net/3bSVw/

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="other">
        <img src="../images/logo.png" width="97" height="97" />
    </div>
    <div id="company">
        <img src="../images/company.png" width="370" height="97" />
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>




#header {
    width:960px;
    background-color:#e9e9e9;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#other {
    float:left;    
}
#company {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Actually, #30 is a perfectly valid ID. In HTML5. It's just that CSS has issues with it. See http://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/